# Rails 5 , sqlite3 using array as column/ attribute issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is how I use array in a rails 5 model
in migration

```
  t.text :diagnoses, array: true, default: []
```

in model

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :diagnoses, Array
end
```

in my seed method I am doing it like

```
  patient = Patient.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', admission: a)
  patient.diagnoses = [1, 2]
  patient.save!
```

It give an error as

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: can't dump `diagnoses`: was supposed to be a Array, but was a Integer. -- 0
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try `patient.diagnoses = [1, 2].to_yaml`.

Comment: "Keep in mind that database adapters handle certain serialization tasks for you. For instance: json and jsonb types in PostgreSQL will be converted between JSON object/array syntax and Ruby Hash or Array objects transparently. There is no need to use serialize in this case." This applies to array types as well. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @SebastianPalma I have tried with `[1, 2].to_yaml` same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago, I encountered this exact issue. I found the following workaround:

- In your migration file:

  ```
  t.text :diagnoses, array: true
  ```
- Then in model:

  ```
  class Patient < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :diagnoses

    after_initialize do |patient|
      patient.diagnoses= [] if patient.diagnoses == nil
    end
  end
  ```
- The `after_initialize` callback will be called whenever an Active Record object is instantiated, either by directly using new or when a record is loaded from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider actually using a relational database properly instead.

```
# since diagnosis is highly irregular we most likely need to configure rails 
# to pluralize it correctly
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'diagnosis', 'diagnoses'
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patient_diagnoses
  has_many :diagnoses, through: patient_diagnoses
end

# this table provides data normalization 
class Diagnosis < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patient_diagnoses
  has_many :patients, through: patient_diagnoses
end

# this is just a join table
class PatientDiagnosis < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :diagnosis
end
```

This lets you use the foreign keys to ensure referential integrity and lets you use ActiveRecord Associations instead of just cobbling together something wonky. There are very few actual advantages of using an array type here.

If you still want to use your array column you should not use [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html). Its used with plain old varchar / text columns to store YAML strings which are serialized/unserialized in Rails. It is a vestige from the dark days before we had native JSON/array types and really does not have any use today besides in legacy applications.

Comment: You make a great point. I had been trying to figure out the best way to add an array column, but I see how that was not the best way to go about it. I wish I would have found this two hours ago.